# multiple folder sync with rsync from server to local storage

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sync, rsync

im trying this for a first time, and im not the best in sh.

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPTPATH='server/cronscripts'  
SSHKEYNAME='keyid'  
FROMDIRPATH='server/source-folder/folderA/'  
TOSERVERANDPATH='local-storage/destination-folder/folderB/'   
FROMDIRPATH='server/source-folder/folderC/'  
TOSERVERANDPATH='local-storage/destination-folder/folderD/'

/usr/bin/rsync -az --no-perms --chmod=777 --delete --rsync-path=/bin/rsync --sparse --hard-links -e "/usr/bin/ssh -i ${SCRIPTPATH}/${SSHKEYNAME}" ${FROMDIRPATH} ${TOSERVERANDPATH}
```

The `.sh` is already existed on the server.
I added the `C->D` sync, hoping that the sh script will do it after `A->B`.
The issue here is that only the `C->D` sync runs, but `A->B` doesn't.

What should i do to make it work?

Comment: You overwrite the variables FROMDIRPATH and TOSERVERANDPATH.

Comment: omg, i feel like a moron. Thank you!